# Next 13.3: How to use NotFound() for a 404 Page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, error-handling

I am using Next 13.3  to create pages dynamically from a `[slug]` folder with the following code in the page.jsx file in that folder:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const pageData = await getPage(slug);
                if (!pageData) {
                    throw new Error("NotFound");
                }
                setPage(pageData);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`error.message = `, error.message)
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [slug]);
```

I need to trigger a 404 page, when there is no associated page returned from the database. From the docs I believe Next can trigger a 404 page when the NotFound function is called.

I have tried using `try catch` but cannot understand how to get this error to call Next's `NotFound` function

EDIT:
I had a bad case of RTFM I had missed how Next recommend you call notFound(). I have now amended the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            // try {
            const pageData = await getPage(slug);
            if (!pageData) {
                notFound()
            } else {
                setPage(pageData);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [slug]);
```

This now produces an error `Error: NEXT_NOT_FOUND` and also `uncaught Error: Minified React error #418;` and `Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423` however it does not render the not-found.jsx 404 page (in fact it renders the layout from the `[slug]` folder and not the root (home) page.

I am hoping that the 418 and 423 errors relate to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50245

Comment: Call `notFound()` does not work?

Comment: @LinDu  Yes I think this is working now, but still not rendering the not-found.jsx

Comment: as far as I know `nofFound()` works only in server components.

Comment: @Yilmaz OK so no SSG? Any thoughts on how else to achive this with SSG?

Comment: try `router.push(404)`

Comment: I have tried this @Yilmaz and I get the error uncaught (in promise) Error: No router instance found. You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize Next.js' server-side rendering function to redirect to a `notFound` page in case the requested data is not found in the database. Consider the following code:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const pageData = getPage(context.query.slug);
  if (!pageData) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
  return {
    props: { pageData },
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks but according to the docs 13.3 can now pick up the error...

The not-found file is used to render UI when the notFound function is thrown within a route segment. Along with serving a custom UI, Next.js will also return a 404 HTTP status code.

However I cannot get this work either in the root or in the [slug] folder